# NEW PRODUCT updating at the wrong time

Tags: products, products-management, date, new-products

One of my clients are having trouble with their magento installation. When they they create a new product and set the "Set Product as New from Date". It does not update until later that day, and not by midnight as expected.

I have tried the following:

- Checking how often the magento cronjob is running,
- Checking the time setting on the server.

Comment: I have never actually spent the time debugging this, but I believe this issue extends to all time based events such as product special prices and design changes.  Definitely something wrong in the core code here - I believe it's actually a full day out.

Comment: I recently found out, they use an extension called: "ProLabels" And there is an update timer, (1 hour, 5 hours, 24 hours). I've changed this to 1 hour, and hoping for the best.